# Python/ Django- how to automatically save a form whenever a value is changed?

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

I have a Django project, and there is a form on one of the pages, on which the user can enter the value of a deposit, and the date that the deposit was received.

When the page is first loaded, these fields are populated with values retrieved from the database. If the user then manually changes these values, and refreshes the page, the values revert back to what they were originally... I want the form to automatically save any time any changes are made to its values, so that if the user changes a value and refreshes the page, the new value should be displayed automatically.

How would I do this?

The HTML for this form is:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax' project.id %}" class="autosave_form full-width">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="col-12 box">
        <div>
            <table class="right fixed m-t-md">
                <tr>
                    {% for hidden in deposit_form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{hidden}}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for field in deposit_form.visible_fields %}
                        <td class="p-r-md">{{field.label}}</td><td class="p-r-md">{{field}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <td><a class="email_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=7">Raise invoice</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 box">
        <div>
            <div class="expand-header"><strong class="m-t-md">Costing notes</strong></div>
            <table class="vertical-table left">
                {% include "projects/includes/stacked_form.html" with form=budget_notes_form %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 box">
        <div>
            <div class="expand-header"><strong class="m-t-md">Project rejected by client?</strong></div>
            <table class="vertical-form left">
                {% include "projects/includes/stacked_form.html" with form=ended_form %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The `concept_save_ajax` view that's being called to save the form is defined in the `views.py` file for this app with:

```
def concept_save_ajax(request, project_id):
""" Save concept forms """
if not request.is_ajax():
    raise Http404('Ajax only')

if request.method == 'POST':
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions', 'budget_overview').get(pk=project_id)

    form_instances = [
        # [DepositForm, project.deposit],
        [DepositInfoForm, project.deposit],
        [BudgetNotesForm, project.budget_overview],
        [EndDetailsForm, project.end],
    ]

    # Save the forms 
    for form_instance in form_instances:
        form = form_instance[0](request.POST, instance=form_instance[1])
        if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
            print form_instance[0], "is valid.", form_instance[0]
            updated_details = form.save()
        elif form.has_changed():
            print form_instance[0], "is not valid", form.errors
            return JsonResponse({'error': form.errors})



    # url = '/projects/{0}/?tab={1}'.format(project_id, tabs[3])
    return JsonResponse({'success': 'Saved'})
else:
    raise Http404('Request is not a post')
```

Why is it that the form is not saving when I make changes to any of the values displayed on it? How can I get the values to remain the same when I refresh the page once they've been changed?

**Edit**

The form as it's defined in `forms.py` is:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    amount_exc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency',}),label="Deposit exc VAT")
    amount_inc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency', 'readonly':'readonly',}),label="Inc VAT")
    date_received = MoonDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ('amount_exc_vat', 'amount_inc_vat', 'date_received')#,'received')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
        try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                'received': project.deposit_received,
                'amount_exc_vat': amount_exc_vat,
                'amount_inc_vat': amount_inc_vat,
                }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(DepositInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_received'].widget.attrs.update({'data-original-value': self.initial['date_received'] or ''})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        deposit = self.instance
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'date_received' in self.changed_data:
            if not data['date_received'] == '':
                deposit.project.deposit_received = True;
                self.deposit_r = True
                deposit.project.upgrade_detailed_status(Project.ds75)
            else:
                deposit.project.deposit_received = False;       
            deposit.project.save()

        if ('amount_exc_vat' in self.changed_data or 'date_received' in self.changed_data or 'received' in self.changed_data) and data['amount_exc_vat'] and data['date_received'] and data['received']:
            send_message(message_template=2, project=self.instance.project)
            self.deposit_r = True       

        if hasattr(self, 'deposit_r'):
            # Make the payment
            deposit_payment = Payment(project=deposit.project, is_booking_deposit=True, amount_exc_vat=data['amount_exc_vat'], date_paid=data['date_received'])

        return super(DepositInfoForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

**Edit**

There are a few JS functions defined at the end of the HTML file for the page that I'm working on- defined as follows (showing the one I think I will want to use):

```
{% block content_scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ical_trigger.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/email_trigger.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){    $(document).ready(function(){


            $('#id_date_received').on('change', function messageDepositPaid(){
                ...
            })
            ...
            $('.update_presentation').on('click', function updatePresentation(){
                var $form = $(this).closest('tbody')
                var name = $form.attr('name');
                $form.hide();
                $('#'+name+' ul').load(location.href + ' #'+name+' ul>*');
            })
            ...
        }); })(jQuery)
    </script>
(% endblock content_scripts %}
```

**Edit**

When I inspect the element that holds the fields I want to be saved in the browser, I can see that they are in a `<table></table>` in a `<div></div>` inside a `<form></form>` which has the attribute `<form method="post" class="autosave_form full-width">`

This indicates to me that the data in that form should be automatically saved... anyone know why it isn't?

Comment: post your submit button of form

Comment: Well, very probably because your not submitting the form via ajax anywhere. Or did you expect it to happen automagically ?

Comment: As a side note: the right HTTP status for an unexpected method is 405 Method not allowed (and the response MUST include an "Allow" header listing allowed methods). Also, you shouldn't block non-ajax requests (it's useless and will only make debugging harder), and if this view is supposed to return json then you should **always** return a `JsonResponse` (even when it's a 404 or 405 or whatever) so clients won't have to check the content type.

Comment: Apologies- I forgot to include the form definition- as I mentioned, I'm new to Python/ Django... I've just added this into my OP- it shows the `save` view.

Comment: Where is your javascript?  Please post the javascript you are using to submit the form.

Comment: I was expecting it to save automatically, any time any of the data in the form is altered... I can't see anywhere in the code I've posted that it's trying to use JavaScript to do this- should it be? Or should Python/ Django be able to handle the save?

Comment: How could this possibly happen *without* JavaScript? And why did you write a save_ajax function if you're not using Ajax?

Comment: Yes, if you want the form to save automatically without the user submitting it, then you should use ajaxform() and ajaxsubmit().  They are valuable tools.

Comment: I didn't write any of this code- I have just taken over the project after the person who originally wrote it left, so I'm just starting to familiarise myself with it- but I've never really used Python/ Django before, and am trying to learn it by looking into fixing existing problems within the software.

Comment: Ah- I've just spotted the JS at the bottom of the HTML file for this page- there is an `update_presentation` function defined there- which is what I would want to use- how would I add it to the form? I'll copy the JS function into my OP now...

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with django - it's basic web programming knowledge, and you'd have the same situation with a pure php implementation. If you want a form to be automatically submited via ajax each time the user edits a field, then you have to write some js code to do so.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I didn't realise that Django didn't handle the Ajax. I've amended my OP to show the JS function that I think I will want to use- the `update_presentation()` one... I'm just a bit unsure how to use it...

Comment: @someone2088 you don't even need javascript to post, just a submit button will do the trick : <input type="submit">.

Comment: The thing is, I don't really want the user to have to click a button to update the details in the form- since the form is already populated when the user visits that page (having got the values from the database), I want the form to automatically update those values in the database whenever they are changed, so that the new values will be there when the user refreshes/ visits the page again. I'm sure this must be possible, since the form already has the current values displayed when I first browse to that page.

Comment: I've edited my OP again to show that the form I am expecting to save data in automatically has an `autosave_form` attribute.